# Is it possible to include a specific string in all log messages in GCP stack driver/log monitor?

Tags: node.js, logging, google-cloud-platform, payload

I am logging some messages in my nodejs code into GCP console, but I would like to insert a specific ID just like JobID in all log messages.
We can assume this as trace information which get entered with all log messages.

[image: sample screenshot that contains same track information in two log entries]

Similarly I would like to add job ID as jsonPayload or textPayload in all log entries.

Comment: You have to build a wrapper in your code that add some value automatically. nothing out of the box on Google Cloud

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks for the response, can you give me some example for reference as I'm new to GCP & NodeJS

Comment: I don't know how to do that in NodeJS

Comment: you can give sample in any language at your comfort so it gives me some clear idea of implementation